# Get List Attachment Stream

Tags: sharepoint-server, web-services, soap

I am trying to get stream of an attachment, I am using Copy.asmx
I can get a stream of a document stored in a document library but for the attachment  I get 0 result.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
<GetItemResponse xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
  <GetItemResult>0</GetItemResult>
</GetItemResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, SPServices is wraped with soap service.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/2014.02/jquery.SPServices.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $().SPServices({
                operation: "GetAttachmentCollection",
                async: false,
                listName: "Test",
                ID: 1,
                completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
                    //suppose only one attachement file
                    $(xData.responseXML).find("Attachment").each(function () {
                        var url = $(this).text();

                        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        request.open('GET', url, true);
                        request.responseType = 'blob';
                        request.onload = function () {
                            var reader = new FileReader();
                            reader.readAsDataURL(request.response);
                            reader.onload = function (e) {
                                //binary stream
                                console.log('DataURL:', e.target.result);
                            };
                        };
                        request.send();
                    });

                }
            });
        })
    </script>
```

Update:

Test result.

[image]

Comment: does this return binary stream in base 64 format?

Comment: Check the update.